# Why aren't images being displayed in my v-data-table

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

So currently I am using v-data-table to display the data being passed into the vue component via a prop. The prop is an array of objects, each object has several fields but the only fields I want to display are name, img, and store.price. Name and price display perfectly fine, but when I try to display an image, only the image link appears in the data table. Can someone take a look at my code and steer me in the right direction?

```
 <template>
        <v-data-table
        v-model="selected"
        :headers="headers"
        :items="displayedTools"
        :items-per-page="10"
        :single-select="singleSelect"
        show-select
        class="elevation-1 tool-table"
      >

    <template slot="items" slot-scope="props">
        <td><img :src="props.item.img" style="width: 10px; height: 10px"></td>
        <td class="text-xs-right">{{ props.item.name }}</td>
        <td class="text-xs-right">{{ props.item.stores.price }}</td>
    </template>
  </v-data-table>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    name: 'ToolResults',
    props: ['found_tools'],
    data() {
        return {
            singleSelect: false,
            selected: [],
            headers: [
            { 
                text: 'Image', 
                value: 'img' 
            },
            {
                text: 'Tool Name',
                align: 'left',
                sortable: true,
                value: 'name',
            },
            { 
                text: 'Price', 
                value: 'stores.price' 
            }
            ],
            displayedTools: [{}]
        }
    },
    created() {
        this.populateTable()
        this.addImages()
    },
    methods: {
        populateTable(){
            this.found_tools.forEach(element => {
                this.displayedTools.push(element);
            });
        },
        //Method might need to be added to display Prices properly because it is an array. 
        displayPrices(){

        },
        //Add Image to rows
        addImages(){
            this.displayedTools.forEach(function(part, index, theArray) {
                //theArray[index].img = "<v-img src=" + theArray[index].img + "><v-img>"
                theArray[index].img = 'https:' + theArray[index].img 
            })
        },
        toToolboxPage(toolbox) {
            console.log(toolbox)
            // The Toolbox.vue compoent is already created. The user just needs to be redirected there
        }
    }
}
</script>

<style>
.tool-table {
    margin: 2em;
}
</style>
```

The result of the above code is:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you haven't closed your img tag at the template.

Also in your `addImages()` method you have commented the line that assign the images and left the one that assigns a string and the v-img tag isn't closed.

So it should be something like:

```
    addImages(){
        this.displayedTools.forEach(function(part, index, theArray) {
            theArray[index].img = "<v-img src=" + theArray[index].img + "></v-img>"
        })
    },
```

Comment: Well, <img> doesn't require  a closing tag in HTML, and the template of the v-data-table is taking the place of the commented out line of the addImages() function. Also, the v-img tag is already closed in my code.

Furthermore, none of those changes address the problem of displaying the actual img rather than a string.